# ng-bootstrap - Carousel not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I'm testing all the components on the ng-bootstrap and for some reason, I can get the carousel to work. All of the other ng-bootstrap components work perfectly fine. After I enter the code from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples, I get a blank white screen when checking the results.

Here is the error message that is in the console.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12087)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12577)
```

Here is the error message that shows on my VS Code problems tab.

```
'Identifier 'images' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member'
at: '31,22'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because `HttpClient` is unavailable and Angular does not know how to resolve it.

To make `HttpClient` available everywhere in the app.

1. Open the root AppModule `app.module.ts`
2. Import the `HttpClientModule` symbol from `@angular/common/http`
3. Add it to the `@NgModule.imports` array

Example *app.module.ts*:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; // Step 2
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, // Step 3
    CarouselModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes. With your help I got it to work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

[httpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) it's a module that allow Angular's apps work with [APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for work with back-end services ng-booststrap does not use this module is possible that this error is because you are using some external resource, anyway this the way to fix it.

1. Go to your App module
2. Import the HttpClientModule symbol from @angular/common/http
3. Add it to the @NgModule imports array

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CarouselModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In Angular most packages must be imported into the module you are going to use them, always check documentation from packages.